# mysql datareader

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am using MySql 5.0. I using Mupliple datareader in same connection i get error message.  Is possible to use multiple Datareader in same connection?

I using Mysql Connection is

```
MySqlConn.ConnectionString = "SERVER=" & gServerName & ";DATABASE=" & DBname & ";user=" & gUserName & ";password=" & gPassword & ";MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
MySqlConn.Open()
```

Please Help Me

Comment: Why would you be wanting to re-use the same conection as within .NET database connections are held in a connect pool?

Answer (score 1):

The DataReader **usually** (excluding SQL Server 2005+) requires a connection all to itself while it is Executing. Until the DataReader's Close method is called, the connection cannot be used by anything else including another DataReader.
However, you can use the DataReader's NextResult method to let it process multiple sets of records one after another.

Comment: IS possible to use multiple datareader in same connection in mysql5.0?

Comment: What data provider are you using for the Connection object?

Comment: The MySqlDataReader doesn't support, i doubt the OledbDataReader or OdbcDataReader support it, so i'll say no.
 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqldatareader.html